# Certificate SSL of my server (on node.js) with variable IP address

Tags: node.js, socket.io, ssl-certificate, ip-address

I have created an HTTPS server with node.js. Its IP address is variable, because host machine is behind a NAT and server Ip address isn't constant. The problem is that every time I try to connect to `https://address_IP_variable`, chrome doesn't recognise trustable because the server certificate does not match the url. I have tried to add ssl certificate to "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" but it isn't enough. I would like to change color https from red to green. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I met same situation, did it solved?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to ensure that the browser bar is green is for the common name in the certificate ( i.e. the domain name ) to be the same as the one the browser is reaching, and the certificate cannot be self-signed ( it must come from a certificate authority ).

Given your rotating IP address, I'm guessing that you're trying to test this in a non-production environment.  If that's the case, I wouldn't worry about implementing a green bar as much as having SSL implemented, period.  Before you roll into production, you can sort out the green bar issue.  :)